# Why are there plants specifically designed for greenhouses?

Tags: tomatoes, greenhouse

I have read that tomatoes for greenhouse culture need to be varieties designed to be grown in greenhouse environments. What are the varieties, and where can I get them...just by mail? And what other plants should I look for that would grow better in a greenhouse than out in the garden? What about normal tomatoes planted in a greenhouse, not out-of-doors in the vegetable garden?  Will they produce well, or under-produce?  How about planting them near the south wall that I open for ventilation, where they'll get direct sun until they are over 3' in height?

Comment: I have found a place nearby that grows tomatoes designed for greenhouses.  I haven't been able to visit nor chat at length with them but any input for 'varieties designed for greenhouses' would be welcome.  I now understand what is going on based on production versus light spectrum wavelength...yadayadayada.  All of the other nurseries I've asked had NEVER HEARD OF SUCH PLANTS. These people grow tomatoes to sell tomatoes!  Not plants.  I hope they'll be ok with telling me how to get my own but I am sure they don't want to make competitors or lose possible clients who just want tomatoes.

Comment: All sounds odd to me - presumably 'varieties designed for greenhouses' won't do well in any other situation then. People in the UK just grow whatever variety they fancy in a greenhouse, with good results. I'm not at all convinced any tomato is 'designed' for greenhouses either, but certainly, some varieties grown outdoors in the UK do much better under glass because of the extra shelter from the vagaries of the weather here.

Comment: Hi Bamboo!! I read a book on greenhouses, i own the book but can't find it yet.  For sure, there are varieties of tomatoes that are meant FOR growing in greenhouses.  You go out and get tomatoes meant for the garden outside, they don't do well in a green house. I'll find the book and author and let you know...I was impressed by this guy (Michael Smith? grin...) a very good book to begin with.  I will let you know and keep looking for me.  And I am sure this is true (97%) so what other plants do better if one finds greenhouse versus outdoor garden varieties!! Thanks!!

Comment: I've just discovered there are greenhouse varieties of cucumber..

Comment: It is amazing. Do you have a greenhouse, Bamboo? Have you been growing regular toms and cucs? How did they do? Space is so precious...getting convinced corn is out of the question...guess it'll be another greenhouse.  Maybe one I can open completely during the day, close up at night.

Comment: The greenhouse book I've found most useful, so far, is by Shane Smith...I think that is the correct guy...

Comment: nope, don't grow veg any more, not enough room, no greenhouse

Answer (score 3):

Plants designed for greenhouse use are bred to work the most efficiently in the greenhouse environment, and resist pests and diseases that prefer greenhouse conditions.

[This site](http://msucares.com/pubs/publications/p1828.pdf) has a list of greenhouse suitable tomato varieties, including easy to find ones like Tropic, Laura, and trust. You can also find detailed information in every department of greenhouse tomato cuture.

Greenhouses are an entirely different environment from outdoor beds, so it is highly advised that you use an adapted variety.

Another plant that will grow much better in a greenhouse is European table cucumbers, which benefit from the uniform heat and humidity all season.

Comment: Thank you! I've got lots of plants started that should be grown outdoors.  What options do I have to improve outdoor vegetables chances to thrive? I'll check out this site and try to get at least greenhouse tomatoes and cucumbers.  Every square inch is precious and I'd prefer not to reinvent the wheel! Grin...

Comment: @stormy :) Basically the key is hardening off. Fertile, ph balanced soil is always best, too.

Comment: Whoa...what a great site!! Thank you! I've had a pH meter for a long time...cost a lot but it has been worth every cent.  I am very into pH and what different plants require. My hoop house is 15X36 and I am having a hard time deciding what to grow and what NOT to grow.  I might have to fore go corn, sad face.  And grow only a small area of potatoes.  My biggest problem is going to be crowding...I'll just get the fans going, use trellis whenever possible.  The site is great, thank you!!!